# jenkins artifactory-release-staging plugin maven-release build fails

Tags: maven, jenkins, perforce, jenkins-plugins, artifactory

using artifactory-release-staging in Jenkins while doing maven release build, i am getting an error 
"ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
java.io.IOException: Perforce execution failed: 'Change 12345 unknown."

using perforce as SCM. And in perforce can able to see changelist saying pending with shelved files(0).
here is my output attached below

"
Building on master in workspace /jenkins/jenkins_home/workspace/jobname
Using master perforce client: jenkins-wrkspc
[jobname] $ /opt1/build_tools/p4/p4 workspace -o jenkins-wrkspc
Saving modified client mavensync:jenkinswrkspc_stggeriatrix
[jobname] $ /opt1/build_tools/p4/p4 -s client -i
Last build changeset: 271790
[jobname] $ /opt1/build_tools/p4/p4 changes -s submitted -m 1 //jenkins-wrkspc/...
[jobname] $ /opt1/build_tools/p4/p4 -s changes -s submitted //jenkins-wrkspc/...@271791,@271790
Sync'ing workspace to changelist 271790.
[jobname] $ /opt1/build_tools/p4/p4 -s sync //jenkins-wrkspc/...@271790
Sync complete, took 8 ms
[RELEASE] Release build triggered
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
java.io.IOException: Perforce execution failed: 'Change 271791 unknown.
'
    at org.jfrog.build.vcs.perforce.PerforceClient.createNewChangeList(PerforceClient.java:88)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.release.scm.perforce.PerforceManager.createNewChangeList(PerforceManager.java:88)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.release.scm.perforce.PerforceCoordinator.beforeReleaseVersionChange(PerforceCoordinator.java:56)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.release.maven.MavenReleaseWrapper.setUp(MavenReleaseWrapper.java:138)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:655)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:585)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1676)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:531)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:231)
Caused by: com.perforce.p4java.exception.RequestException: Change 271791 unknown.

```
at com.perforce.p4java.impl.mapbased.server.Server.handleErrorStr(Server.java:3834)
at com.perforce.p4java.impl.mapbased.server.Server.getChangelist(Server.java:2395)
at com.perforce.p4java.impl.mapbased.client.Client.createChangelist(Client.java:619)
at org.jfrog.build.vcs.perforce.PerforceClient.createNewChangeList(PerforceClient.java:84)
... 9 more
```

[RELEASE] Reverting local changes
Finished: FAILURE"

Answer (score 0):

Has the changelist been renumbered? This is a race condition, due to Perforce's lack of locks on jobs. This is more of a Perforce issue than a Jenkins issue.